# SQL Replication is_subscribed flag is set as 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-replication

We have a Chain store environment using SQL replication. For upgrading the SQL Server we will remove the replication components from the stores and will do the SQL upgrade and then will add the stores back to the Chain. The problem here is SQL  Server is not upgrading from 2008 R2 to 2012 as the `is_subscribed` flag is 1. As I am aware of the `is_subscribed` flag is no longer used in SQL Server and was using on and before 6.5. I doubt the customer might be carrying the database from then and it is throwing the issue now in `SQL 2012`. The question is how to update the flag to 0. We can run the upgrade only if this is set to 0. I have tried executing `sp_dropsubscripion` and `sp_removereplicationdb`. But no luck. Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the below code

```
EXEC sp_dboption 'DBName','subscribed',FALSE
```